# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while starting WebLogic

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

I am using Weblogic 8.1 to deploy my application which is receiving messages from a JMS queue and sending the reply to a JMS queue. I am facing an issue that sometimes when I start the application, it cannot read or send the message to the queue. I searched the server startup logs and found the following exceptions on startup:

```
 ####<2018-10-16 13:23:04 CEST> <Info> <EJB> <doha.tdk.dk> <fasigw_admin> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <ade81e449c4e7b2b:-45336e74:165f5d8969b:-7ffd-0000000001a3fe3e> <1539688984732> <BEA-010213> <Message-Driven EJB: testMdb's transaction was rolledback. The transaction details are: Xid=BEA1-00098814718360AD76D4(25689410),Status=Rolled back. [Reason=Unknown],numRepliesOwedMe=0,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=0,seconds left=300,XAServerResourceInfo[WLStore_fasigw_domain__WLS_fasigw_admin]=(ServerResourceInfo[WLStore_fasigw_domain__WLS_fasigw_admin]=(state=rolledback,assigned=fasigw_admin),xar=WLStore_fasigw_domain__WLS_fasigw_admin30348759,re-Registered = false),SCInfo[fasigw_domain+fasigw_admin]=(state=rolledback),OwnerTransactionManager=ServerTM[ServerCoordinatorDescriptor=(CoordinatorURL=fasigw_admin+10.74.104.20:8602+fasigw_domain+t3+, XAResources={WLStore_fasigw_domain__WLS_fasigw_admin},NonXAResources={})],CoordinatorURL=fasigw_admin+10.74.104.20:8602+fasigw_domain+t3+).> 
    ####<2018-10-16 13:23:04 CEST> <Warning> <EJB> <doha.tdk.dk> <fasigw_admin> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <ade81e449c4e7b2b:-45336e74:165f5d8969b:-7ffd-0000000001a3fe3e> <1539688984733> <BEA-010065> <MessageDrivenBean threw an Exception in onMessage(). The exception was:
     java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: create.
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: create
        at com.clarify.cbo.KJniDisp.create(Native Method)
        at com.clarify.cbo.KJniDisp.createObject(KJniDisp.java:838)
        at com.clarify.cbo.KJniDisp.<init>(KJniDisp.java:812)
        at com.clarify.cbo.Application.<init>(Application.java:81)
        at com.mdb.TestMdb.onMessage(TestMdb.java:37)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:429)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:335)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:291)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4060)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:3953)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:4467)
        at weblogic.work.ServerWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(ServerWorkManagerImpl.java:518)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
    > 
    ####<2018-10-16 13:23:04 CEST> <Warning> <EJB> <doha.tdk.dk> <fasigw_admin> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1539688984734> <BEA-010216> <The Message-Driven EJB: testMdb is throwing exception when processing the messages. Delivery failed after 10 attempts. The EJB container will suspend the message delivery for 5 seconds before retry.> 
    ####<2018-10-16 13:23:04 CEST> <Info> <EJB> <doha.tdk.dk> <fasigw_admin> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <ade81e449c4e7b2b:-45336e74:165f5d8969b:-7ffd-0000000001a3fe3e> <1539688984740> <BEA-010213> <Message-Driven EJB: IgwMdb's transaction was rolledback. The transaction details are: Xid=BEA1-000B8814718360AD76D4(11372590),Status=Rolled back. [Reason=Unknown],numRepliesOwedMe=0,numRepliesOwedOthers=0,seconds since begin=0,seconds left=300,XAServerResourceInfo[WLStore_fasigw_domain__WLS_fasigw_admin]=(ServerResourceInfo[WLStore_fasigw_domain__WLS_fasigw_admin]=(state=rolledback,assigned=fasigw_admin),xar=WLStore_fasigw_domain__WLS_fasigw_admin30348759,re-Registered = false),SCInfo[fasigw_domain+fasigw_admin]=(state=rolledback),OwnerTransactionManager=ServerTM[ServerCoordinatorDescriptor=(CoordinatorURL=fasigw_admin+10.74.104.20:8602+fasigw_domain+t3+, XAResources={WLStore_fasigw_domain__WLS_fasigw_admin},NonXAResources={})],CoordinatorURL=fasigw_admin+10.74.104.20:8602+fasigw_domain+t3+).> 
    ####<2018-10-16 13:23:04 CEST> <Warning> <EJB> <doha.tdk.dk> <fasigw_admin> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <ade81e449c4e7b2b:-45336e74:165f5d8969b:-7ffd-0000000001a3fe3e> <1539688984741> <BEA-010065> <MessageDrivenBean threw an Exception in onMessage(). The exception was:
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:501)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:354)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:307)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.BaseEJBManager.allocateBean(BaseEJBManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.manager.MessageDrivenManager.createBean(MessageDrivenManager.java:279)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.pool.MessageDrivenPool.createBean(MessageDrivenPool.java:165)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.pool.MessageDrivenPool.getBean(MessageDrivenPool.java:90)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.execute(MDListener.java:393)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.transactionalOnMessage(MDListener.java:335)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.MDListener.onMessage(MDListener.java:291)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.onMessage(JMSSession.java:4060)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession.execute(JMSSession.java:3953)
        at weblogic.jms.client.JMSSession$UseForRunnable.run(JMSSession.java:4467)
        at weblogic.work.ServerWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(ServerWorkManagerImpl.java:518)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
```

Can anyone please guide me how to solve these errors?

Comment: Did you added all required jar files? (javax.jms.jar, oracle-weblogic.jar and wlthint3client.jar)

Comment: In the application ear file or in the server?

Comment: within the application

Comment: Yes I have included all the required jars

Comment: so is `com.clarify.cbo.KJniDisp.create()`  something part of your MDB code? I guess, its not.

Comment: It is part of the jars that I am using